# Find roots of the polynomial $p(y)=\alpha y^4 +(2\alpha^2+\alpha-1)y^2 -(2\alpha+1)$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, polynomials, roots

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. I am trying to find the roots of the polynomial
$$p(y)=\alpha y^4 +(2\alpha^2+\alpha-1)y^2 -(2\alpha+1).$$
Having $t=y^2$, I tried computing the $\Delta$ of
$$\alpha t^2 +(2\alpha^2+\alpha-1)t -(2\alpha+1)=0.$$
but it seems that nothing can be collected to have something easy.

Could someone please help me with that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let $\,\beta = 2\alpha+1\,$ then the quadratic is $\,\alpha t^2 + (\alpha\beta-1) t - \beta=\dots\,$

Comment: Direct approach $D=(2\alpha^2+\alpha-1)^2+4\alpha(2\alpha+1)=$
$(2\alpha^2+\alpha-1)^2+4(2\alpha^2+\alpha-1)+4=$
$(2\alpha^2+\alpha-1+2)^2=(2\alpha^2+\alpha+1)^2$,
$t_{1,2}=\frac{-(2\alpha^2+\alpha-1)\pm(2\alpha^2+\alpha+1)}{2\alpha}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $2α^2+α-1 = α(2α+1) - 1$ which is also present in the “—4ac” term of the discriminant. Let $α(2α+1) = z$. Then the discriminant is

     $(z-1)^2 -4α(—(2α+1)) = (z-1)^2+4z$

     $= (z+1)^2 = (α(2α+1)+1)^2$.
I hope you can proceed from here.